# Generate nav for page and append to appropriate nav item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have a navigation that is manually updated (which is incredibly painful). I have something set up to create a sub-navigation based on the page content.

The problem is this is only useful currently for one page as I'm checking for that page class explicitly. Can't wrap my head around a way to make this a bit more flexible to apply to all pages.

Picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]
Code thus far to achieve this desired effect (keep in mind it isn't modular and works in this one instance):

```
   // create array to hold section IDs
   var $navlinksModule = [];
   // find each content section on the page
   // push it to the array created above
   $('.module').each(function(){
       $navlinksModule.push($(this).attr('id'));
   });


   // for each item in the array
   // create a nav link 
   // and append it to this particular nav
   for (var i = 0; i < $navlinksModule.length; i++) {
      $('.cc-nav').append('<li><a href="#' + $navlinksModule[i] + '">' + $navlinksModule[i] + '</a></li>');
   };
```

Looking for it to do the following:

- Determine the page its on (each page has a page-specific class)
- Store that (if necessary?)
- Check the page data, store its ID's for the nav
- Find the appropriate nav section
- Apply it to that nav section.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. I would store objects in the array, however, as it sounds like you want more than an array really will easily give you. You could, then, make your other tests in the process of collating your array:

```
$('.module').each(function(){
   // create an object...
   var theModule = {};
   theModule.id = $(this).attr('id');
   theModule.text = theModule.id;
   // vague guess, since I don't know how the rest of your markup works...
   // but this is where you'd add a flag that says if this module is the current one
   theModule.isCurrent = $('#divThatHasMyPageIdentifierClass').hasClass(theModule.id);
   // add the object to your array
   $navlinksModule.push(theModule);
});
```

The rest of your requirements are much more speculative, and I'd need to see more of your structure to give you a better idea of how to approach that. Just remember that if you store objects in the array, you'll have to access their properties for comparisons, rather than just the objects.

Comment: This is awesome @jason thanks for helping out. I wasn't sure if objects would be the best bet here. Then again, its not often they *aren't* the best bet. 

Few questions: theModule.id would not be the class name of the page. Which is where I'm getting stuck. If a page has a generic class like "childrensclub-page" (name of a product) on this particular page but then another product page has "anotherproduct-page" how can I account for that?

Comment: Do you have a common class or ID you can check? Another thing you can do is use a wildcarded test. `$('[class*="-page"]').attr('class');` would get you the class-attribute content of any element that has a classname containing '-page'.